# DialogFragment orientation independent from main Activity orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-dialogfragment

My application draws a football field (SurfaceView) which is fixed in portrait orientation. A DialogFragment (translucend, so that the field is visible in the background) shows options to the user from time to time.
I would like to have the DialogFragment changing orientation as the device changes, nevertheless, the football field must remain fixed in orientation (always portrait) regardless of the device position. I tried using 2 activities, activity "A" is set with orientation 'portrait' (the football field) and activity "B" is set with 'sensor' (this one creates the dialog). The problem is, everytime the dialog is created by "B" and changes orientation, the whole background football field also changes. How can I avoid this ?

Comment: You could try a dialog-themed activity, instead of a dialog, with `sensor` and see if that helps, though I am not hopeful.

Comment: Just tried the dialog-themed activity - Got the same behaviour.

Comment: can you provide more implementation details?

Answer (score 0):

Not the nicest solution on my eyes but... had to solve by rotating the football field so that it remains in the orientation I wanted after the device changes the orientation.